# safariからiPhoneのバイブレーションを動かす

Tags: javascript, ios, html

safariから画面をタップした時にiPhoneのバイブレーションを動かしたいのですが方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3):

[Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc](https://caniuse.com/) によれば、 Safari は [Vibration API](https://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/) に対応していないため、現状では不可能だと思います<sup>[[1]](https://caniuse.com/#feat=vibration)</sup>。

[image: Can I use では Safari が Vibration API に未対応とされている]

限定的な代替案になりますが、 React Native などのモバイルアプリケーション開発フレームワークを用いて、[ネイティブモジュールを介したバイブレーション機能へのアクセス](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/vibration)を行なうことで、 [Vibration API](https://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/) に未対応であった場合でも、バイブレーション機能を動作させることが出来ます。

Comment: もしくは、 Safari でのバイブレーションを諦め、その他 Vibration API に対応しているブラウザを使用する、ということも解決策の 1 つとして考えられます。